# Why can't a collection be inserted into an array

Tags: excel, vba

Confused why, when attempting to add a collection to an array, I get runtime error 450, `wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment`

Does VBA not allow this activity? Or is different syntax required?

```
Sub collectionTest()

    Dim x As New Collection
    x.Add ("Hello")

    Dim someArr(0 To 0) As Variant
    someArr(0) = x

End Sub
```

Comment: You need to use `Set`.

Comment: Thanks for the catch...I've forgotten about the set / object rule too many times. Thanks.